# List view not hiding/unhiding elements based on a state variable

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I've got a List of NavigationLinks. Each NavigationLink is wrapped by a "isVisible" boolean check.
Separately, a config page has Toggle's that set the visibility on or off.

The problem is when I come back from the config page, the main view doesnt update itself based on the new visibility boolean on all the items. i.e. the "if (hv.isVisible)" isn't reevaluated.

I know the booleans are being persisted. When I restart the app, the correct items in the list are shown

```
@ObservedObject fileprivate var viewModel = HealthValuesViewModel.instance
// in here values is defined as
// @Published var values: [HealthValue] = []
// which is then populated in init()
// The HealthValue is an ObservableObject class and has property
// @Published var isVisible: Bool

List(viewModel.values, id:\.type.rawValue) { hv in
    if (hv.isVisible) {
        NavigationLink(destination: hv.view) {
            HealthValueCellView(healthValue: hv )
        }
    }
}
```

I've been playing with all sorts of combinations of @ObervedObject, @Published etc.
Also tried making sure I have an id in the List.

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
As suggested, I've created a reproducible example. Hope this makes things clearer

```
// DummyView is the main view - has a settings button and a list of 3 objects.
// DummySettingsView is the sub-view where the items in the list are toggled on/off
// DummySettingsCellView are the elements in the settings view list that have the toggle

import SwiftUI


enum ValueType: String {
case type1 = "T1"
case type2 = "T2"
case type3 = "T3"
}

class DummyValueObject : Identifiable, ObservableObject {
let type: ValueType
let symbolName: String

@Published var isVisible: Bool = true {
    didSet {
        print("ValueObject type=\(type.rawValue), isVisible = \(isVisible)")
    }
}

init(type: ValueType, symbolName: String) {
    self.type = type
    self.symbolName = symbolName
}
}

class DummyViewModel : ObservableObject {
static let instance = DummyViewModel()

@Published var values: [DummyValueObject] = [
    DummyValueObject(type: .type1, symbolName: "heart.fill"),
    DummyValueObject(type: .type2, symbolName: "wind"),
    DummyValueObject(type: .type3, symbolName: "scalemass.fill")
]
}



struct DummySettingCellView: View {
@ObservedObject var value: DummyValueObject

var body: some View {
    HStack {
        Image(systemName: value.symbolName)
        Text(value.type.rawValue)
        Toggle("", isOn: $value.isVisible)
    }
}
}

struct DummySettingsView: View {
@ObservedObject var model = DummyViewModel.instance

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        List(model.values) { v in
            DummySettingCellView(value: v)
        }
    }
}
}


struct DummyView: View {

@ObservedObject var model = DummyViewModel.instance

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        NavigationLink(destination: DummySettingsView()) {
            Image(systemName: "wrench")
        }
        Spacer()
        
        List(model.values, id:\.type.rawValue) { v in
            if (v.isVisible) {
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: v.symbolName)
                    Text(v.type.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I should probably have mentioned that this is a watch app - but I guess it shouldnt make a difference.

Comment: This needs a [mre]. I’m very suspicious of HealthValuesViewModel.instance but you haven’t included the necessary code to see if it is the problem.

Comment: have you tried using `@StateObject ...` and pass the`viewModel` into your `config page` view

Comment: Every `ObservableObject` has to be wrapped in a `View` you need `@ObservedObject var hv: HealthValue` in a subview.

Comment: Here is a pretty small reproducible example... Hope this makes things clearer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach, using a `struct` for the `DummyValueObject` instead of a nested `ObservableObject`, and a `@Binding var value: DummyValueObject` to pass it into `DummySettingCellView`

Also note, the **important** use of `List(model.values.filter{$0.isVisible})` instead of using
`if (v.isVisible) {...}`, to allow the view to refresh properly.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {  // <-- here
            DummyView()
        }
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DummyViewModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DummySettingsView(model: model)) { // <-- here
                Image(systemName: "wrench")
            }
            Spacer()

            List(model.values.filter{$0.isVisible}) { v in // <-- here important
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: v.symbolName)
                    Text(v.type.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DummySettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DummyViewModel  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($model.values) { $v in  // <-- here
                DummySettingCellView(value: $v)  // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

class DummyViewModel : ObservableObject {

    @Published var values: [DummyValueObject] = [
        DummyValueObject(type: .type1, symbolName: "heart.fill"),
        DummyValueObject(type: .type2, symbolName: "wind"),
        DummyValueObject(type: .type3, symbolName: "scalemass.fill")
    ]
}

struct DummyValueObject : Identifiable {  // <-- here
    let id = UUID()  // <-- here
    
    let type: ValueType
    let symbolName: String
    
    var isVisible: Bool = true {
        didSet {
            print("---> DummyValueObject type=\(type.rawValue), isVisible = \(isVisible)")
        }
    }
    
    init(type: ValueType, symbolName: String) {
        self.type = type
        self.symbolName = symbolName
    }
}

struct DummySettingCellView: View {
    @Binding var value: DummyValueObject   // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: value.symbolName)
            Text(value.type.rawValue)
            Toggle("", isOn: $value.isVisible)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

enum ValueType: String {
    case type1 = "T1"
    case type2 = "T2"
    case type3 = "T3"
}
```

EDIT-1

You can of course use (not recommended), your **nested** `ObservableObjects`.
In that case, follow this approach, still using `@Binding var value: DummyValueObject` in `DummySettingCellView`, it will fix your current problem, but may create others
in the other parts of your code, if not now, then later on.

Note, you should not use `@ObservedObject var model = DummyViewModel.instance` thinking
you can use it as a singleton in different views, **this is not correct**.

The `@StateObject var model = DummyViewModel()` in `DummyView` should be the
**only** source of truth for your app. Pass this model around to the views that need it.

Have a look at this link, it gives you some good official examples of how to manage data in your app
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app)

```
class DummyViewModel : ObservableObject {
    //static let instance = DummyViewModel()  <--- NOT THIS
    
    @Published var values: [DummyValueObject] = [
        DummyValueObject(type: .type1, symbolName: "heart.fill"),
        DummyValueObject(type: .type2, symbolName: "wind"),
        DummyValueObject(type: .type3, symbolName: "scalemass.fill")
    ]
}

struct DummySettingCellView: View {
    @Binding var value: DummyValueObject  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Image(systemName: value.symbolName)
            Text(value.type.rawValue)
            Toggle("", isOn: $value.isVisible)
        }
    }
}

struct DummySettingsView: View {
    @ObservedObject var model: DummyViewModel // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List($model.values) { $v in         // <-- here $
                DummySettingCellView(value: $v) // <-- here
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DummyView: View {
    @StateObject var model = DummyViewModel()  // <-- here
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationLink(destination: DummySettingsView(model: model)) {  // <-- here
                Image(systemName: "wrench")
            }
            Spacer()
            
            // -- here --
            List(model.values.filter{$0.isVisible}, id:\.type.rawValue) { v in
                HStack {
                    Image(systemName: v.symbolName)
                    Text(v.type.rawValue)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great - reallt helpful, thanks.
- I had acceped that my singleton approach was lazy - agree it should be created by the owner and passd around
- I still think it's useful to have my model objects as classes rather than structs, but will think further on this
- The .filter{$0.isVisible} is far more elegant than if(v.isVisible) but it didnt make a difference
- The thing that made it work was the $ in the DummySettingsView, and changing my ObservedObject to Binding - I need to read up more on these to understand fully.